# what is Iot hub in xamarin app?

Tags: xamarin, azure-iot-hub

i have started working on a new project that is in xamarin native.
i have idea about xamarin.forms and web rest web api integration in that.

but in this project it seems it used azure and i found many configuration of field like this

> string strTemp =    "#{IotHubConnectionString}#";

i have lots of question about this as i feel i am totally new to this.Can anybody clear my questions?

1) what is IoT hub and why it is used for?

2) what is azure. Is it same like rest api? any link to understand it in detail from scratch.

3) as shown in above syntax how will strTemp get value as #{IotHubConnectionString}# is in "" so it will not be treated as normal static string??

please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually IoT Hub, which stands for Internet of Things (IoT) Hub. It's used for gathering and managing Internet of Things data/devices, you can read more about it [on official IoT Hub website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/iot-hub/). Also [here on MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/iotdev/2017/05/09/understand-different-connection-strings-in-azure-iot-hub/) you can find a detailed description of connection strings in IoT, for example it shows how to find the connection strings in Azure website:

[image]

Your code:

```
string strTemp = "#{IotHubConnectionString}#";
```

can either:

1) mean that you should just paste IoT Hub connection string, so like this:

```
string strTemp = "#{HostName=...}#";
```

2) or it is using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), a C# feature available from 6.0 version. Actually it should have a dollar sign to work correctly, like this:

```
string IotHubConnectionString = "HostName=...";
string strTemp = $"#{IotHubConnectionString}#";
```

If you want to learn more about Azure in general, I recommend looking at their [official page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-azure/) and then look for tutorials for various specific things Azure can help you with. It's a set of cloud services, so you can do many things there like setting up a server with an API, database or hosting some virtual machines - possibilities are basically endless.

Comment: if i need to set its value like that then y i cant just assign that value directly to stTemp? why i need to put it in "# #"?

Comment: what it stands for?its just format that we need to append to string?

Comment: I edited my answer with a dollar added to your code, so string interpolation works (if you're using C# 6 or above). Of course you can just put your hostname straight into "#here#".

Comment: and  what is azure used for ? is it same like rest api?

Comment: any link from which i can go thought and learn about it.as i m totaly anaware of that

Comment: I edited my answer with Azure info, if you think it's an answer to your question, then please mark it as such for others ;) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> Azure IoT Hub is a fully managed service that enables reliable and
>   secure bidirectional communications between millions of IoT devices
>   and a solution back end.

For a simple sample, you can send a message from a device to azure iot hub and receive this message in your device that running xamarin app. Vice versa. That is bidirectional communication between devices. Azure iot hub can do more than that.

There are [SDKs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks) for a variety of languages and platforms that help connect devices to azure iot hub.

And also you can use [REST api for azure iot hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/).

You can get an overview of azure iot hub from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-what-is-iot-hub).

Get started and find Extended IoT scenarios from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-get-started-simulated).

These resources you may interest in:

[Xamarin with Azure IoT Hub](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/dotnetConf/2017/T329)

[Connect iOS, Android and Windows devices to Azure IoT Suite Remote Monitoring using Xamarin](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-hub-xamarin-remote-monitoring-device)

If you have any problem with using azure iot hub. Ask a question here I am glad to help you.